# How to completely DISallow interface property overriding

Tags: typescript

Consider the following case:

```
interface A {
  sup: string;
}

interface B extends A {
  sup: "good" | "not good";
}
```

In this case lint does not give me any errors, because I am redefining the `sup` property with a "subtype" that is compatible with string and it is allowing for that.

I want it to warn me if I am even attempting to override it, it does not matter if the new definition is compatible with the old one.

The reason I want to do this is because I have a case with React where I am taking all the base HTML props that a component has and I am extending an interface with it, however since I can not know all of the reserved HTML properties, I want to protect myself against overriding them, so if `sup` was such property, I should not be able to redefine it at all, no matter if its compatible.

A real case within React would be:

```
type HTMLButtonProps = JSX.IntrinsicElements["button"];

export interface ButtonProps extends HTMLButtonProps {
  // color: number; // this will throw an error:

  // interface ButtonProps
  // Interface 'ButtonProps' incorrectly extends interface 'ClassAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> & ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>'.
  // Type 'ButtonProps' is not assignable to type 'ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>'.
  // Types of property 'color' are incompatible.
  // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

  // And the above is fine!

  // But I want the same for this case
  // I should not be able to do this either:
  // color: "primary" | "secondary";
}
```

Comment: You can use [workaround](https://tsplay.dev/wepqdW)

Comment: Can you articulate why you don't want to allow this?  What, specifically, goes wrong in this case?  Ideally you'd show a [mre] where something bad happens if you allow overriding properties with subtypes.  I ask because no matter what you do, nothing will absolutely prevent such subtypes from existing and being compatible... TS is structural, not nominal, so someone can always pass `HTMLButtonProps & {color: "blah"}` in where `HTMLButtonProps` is wanted.  Therefore the actual use case is relevant to the potential answer.

Comment: @jcalz the use case is the following - I am using `styled-components` to style my components, however I am changing the way I am using `styled-components` and with my "new way" I do not have an easy way to destructure properties that I pass down to the components, and if I accidently use a property that is a reserved html property, it will override the default one and get passed to the DOM if I do not destructure it, however if I also "go back" to my old way which allowed for destructuring, it becomes less appealing to use "the new way", so I just want to protect myself from overriding default

Comment: html properties, by accident:)

Comment: Do you have a [mre] of that use case? (Code and not just a verbal description) Maybe this question needs to be tagged as `styled-components` if you need it to understand the use case?